# write comma seperated list value to text file in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list in which each values are comma separated. 
I need to write a text file with each comma separated value as next line.

I am adding below my list:

```py
my_list = ['add IPAddress name=Sevone Address=10.241.46.0/25, 10.241.46.128/25, 10.241.47.0/27', 'add ServiceUDP name=Sevone_Service DestinationPorts=161  162', 'add IPAddress name=CMG Address=10.95.67.128/26,10.95.67.192/26', 'add IPAddress name=DNS Address=10.95.58.168/29,10.95.58.192/28', 'add IPAddress name=FW Address=10.95.58.208/28', 'add IPAddress name=SRAS, Enrichment Server Address=10.19.71.0/25, 10.19.72.0/24, 10.19.75.194, 10.19.75.195, 10.19.75.196, 10.19.75.210, 10.40.46.0/25, 10.40.55.0/24', 'add ServiceUDP name=SRAS, Enrichment Server_Service DestinationPorts=10080, 22, 2222, 23, 443, 5900, 80, 8085, 8143, 8443, 9097, 9098, 80, 8080.161,162', 'add IPAddress name=CMG Address=10.95.67.128/26,10.95.67.192/26', 'add IPAddress name=SPS Address=10.95.59.64/26', 'add IPAddress name=DNS Address=10.95.58.168/29,10.95.58.192/28', 'add IPAddress name=FW Address=10.95.58.208/28']
```

Comment: Please format your question properly (with code blocks) and indicate clearly what input/output you expect along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for method [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
In [1]: my_list = ['add IPAddress name=Sevone Address=10.241.46.0/25, 10.241.46.128/25, 10.241.47.0/27', 'add ServiceUDP name=Sevone_Servic
    ...: e DestinationPorts=161 162', 'add IPAddress name=CMG Address=10.95.67.128/26,10.95.67.192/26', 'add IPAddress name=DNS Address=10.9
    ...: 5.58.168/29,10.95.58.192/28', 'add IPAddress name=FW Address=10.95.58.208/28', 'add IPAddress name=SRAS, Enrichment Server Address=
    ...: 10.19.71.0/25, 10.19.72.0/24, 10.19.75.194, 10.19.75.195, 10.19.75.196, 10.19.75.210, 10.40.46.0/25, 10.40.55.0/24', 'add ServiceUD
    ...: P name=SRAS, Enrichment Server_Service DestinationPorts=10080, 22, 2222, 23, 443, 5900, 80, 8085, 8143, 8443, 9097, 9098, 80, 8080.
    ...: 161,162', 'add IPAddress name=CMG Address=10.95.67.128/26,10.95.67.192/26', 'add IPAddress name=SPS Address=10.95.59.64/26', 'add I
    ...: PAddress name=DNS Address=10.95.58.168/29,10.95.58.192/28', 'add IPAddress name=FW Address=10.95.58.208/28']

In [2]: print("\n".join(my_list))
add IPAddress name=Sevone Address=10.241.46.0/25, 10.241.46.128/25, 10.241.47.0/27
add ServiceUDP name=Sevone_Service DestinationPorts=161 162
add IPAddress name=CMG Address=10.95.67.128/26,10.95.67.192/26
add IPAddress name=DNS Address=10.95.58.168/29,10.95.58.192/28
add IPAddress name=FW Address=10.95.58.208/28
add IPAddress name=SRAS, Enrichment Server Address=10.19.71.0/25, 10.19.72.0/24, 10.19.75.194, 10.19.75.195, 10.19.75.196, 10.19.75.210, 10.40.46.0/25, 10.40.55.0/24
add ServiceUDP name=SRAS, Enrichment Server_Service DestinationPorts=10080, 22, 2222, 23, 443, 5900, 80, 8085, 8143, 8443, 9097, 9098, 80, 8080.161,162
add IPAddress name=CMG Address=10.95.67.128/26,10.95.67.192/26
add IPAddress name=SPS Address=10.95.59.64/26
add IPAddress name=DNS Address=10.95.58.168/29,10.95.58.192/28
add IPAddress name=FW Address=10.95.58.208/28
```

Now if you want to save this as a text file, just use the following:

```py
with open("file_name.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(my_list))
```

Comment: I am able to get the expected output. Thanx for your help.

Comment: My pleasure. Please "accept" my answer then, thanks!